# Cannot open IJulia; it instead starts IPython

Tags: ipython, julia, ijulia-notebook

How can I use IJulia in my browser?

When I start to open it by executing `ipython notebook --profile julia` on my Terminal, a new window opens on my browse - however, it is IPython notebook, not IJulia notebook.

Why does it show IPython? For your information, I use Python 2.7.5 and iPython 1.1, and 0.2.0 for Julia. Also, when I tried running `Pkg.add("IJulia")`, `INFO: Nothing to be done.` was shown on my screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably just a caching issue of the logo. Try executing some code to see if the kernel is actually python or Julia. IJulia notebook is actually an IPython notebook, but which talk to Julia in the back.

Comment: No, when I wrote some code there and ran it, the kernel assumed python - hence when I wrote `for ~ end` syntax, it spitted out an error.

Comment: Did console say anything special ? Can you check what `cat  $(ipython locate)/profile_julia/ipython_config.py | grep -v '^#'` say ? (something which look like `c.KernelManager.kernel_cmd = [".../julia", ".../kernel.jl", "{connection_file}"]`). If not try deleting julia profile and run `Pkg.fixup('IJulia')` IIRC.

Comment: You are right, that I didn't have `ipython_config.py` in `~/.ipython/profile_julia`. And then run `Pkg.fixup("IJulia")` and IJulia console starts to open successfully on my browser. Thanks!

Comment: @Matt Your answer is displaying accented characters?

Comment: Thanks! In case it helps others in the future:

"WARNING: fixup is deprecated, use build instead."

Comment: I had the same issue and a simple `Pkg.build("IJulia")` resolved it, suspecting it might have been caused by a faulty installation-order.